# Perl : String containing a variable value pattern

Tags: string, perl

I'm passing in various names in a variable $k_name. I want to see if a string ($txt_string) contains the name stored in the variable '$k_name'.

Code that I've tried:

```
if ($string =~ /$k_name/)
{
     print TXTFILE "Got Name: ".$k_name."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @choroba "Why isn't it working?" *{scurries away}*

Comment: It will not work if `$k_name` contains a regex meta character, e.g. `+`, `?`, `[` etc. `/\Q$k_name/` would solve that.

Answer (score 2):

If by “contains” you mean a real substring, there's no need for regular expressions, just use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html):

```
if (-1 < index $txt_string, $k_name) {
    print TXTFILE "Got name: $k_name.\n";
}
```

Make sure `$k_name` doesn't contain any whitespace (final newline).

BTW, your example code works for me for the following values:

```
my $k_name = 'John';
my $txt_string = 'Joe Smith John Doe';
```